# Sprint transaction - REQUIRES_NEW behavior if the inner transaction fails

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

Suppose I have two transactions, and the inner transaction propagation is REQUIRES_NEW.

So, the first transaction which is running on transaction X, and the second one creates a new transaction. And suppose if the inner transaction fails, does the outer transaction also fails? or only the inner transaction will only fail, making the outer transaction to succeed.

Could anyone please explain the behavior in the above scenario?

Appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're separate transactions (the outer transaction is suspended while the inner runs), not nested transactions. If the inner transaction fails, it's rolled back. If you suppress that exception you can still have the outer transaction succeed, *if you choose so*.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman. So if we didnt suppress the inner transaction failure exception, the out transaction also fails. Is this right?

Comment: Exactly, and as you usually wouldn't have a `catch(Exception)` around it, in normal cases both transactions would fail. Still, you could easily catch exceptions and for example retry if it fails (and it makes sense to retry).

Comment: Is there a way we can add exception handling for the inner transactions? If not, then if the inner transaction fails, the outer transaction fill also fails always. right?

Comment: Rollback is controlled by exceptions. You can configure which exceptions cause rollback in the `@Transactional` annotation, or catch exceptions yourself and not let them propagate.